# Please help to crack a sql query to fetch a record using self join or any other way

Tags: sql

I have a table Cust with two columns custid and flag.And there are records with flags u,i for same custid.
I just want to fetch records which are having only flag as U but not I.
Example:

Cust Table:

```
custid  flag
123      U
123      I
124      U
124      I
125      U
126      U
126      I
127      U
127      U
```

I want to pick custid 125 and and 127 as they dont have flag I.

Please suggest a query.

Answer (score 2):

If you group around your `custid` you can select only the ones where no `flag = 'I'` exists.

```
select custid
from cust
group by custid
having count(case when flag = 'I' 
                  then 1 
                  else 0
             end) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM CUST
WHERE FLAG = 'U' AND
  CUSTID NOT IN (SELECT CUSTID FROM CUST WHERE FLAG = 'I')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another approach. (**[Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1cc07/7)**)

```
select x.custId 
from cust x
      left join (select custId from cust where flag = 'I') y
      on x.custId = y.custId
where y.custId is null 
group by x.custId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct custid from cust
MINUS
select distinct custid from cust where flag = 'I'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct c.custid from cust c where (select count(*) 
from cust where custid = c.custid and flag = 'I') = 0
```

Get the number of the customer having `flag` as `'I'` , if it's `equal to 0` then select that `custid` it.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.num, a.custid
from
(select count(flag) as num, custid
from cust
group by custid) as a
inner join 
(select count(flag) as num, custid
    from cust
    where flag = 'U'
    group by custid) as b
on a.custid = b.custid
and a.num = b.num
```

this is the result:

[image]